# Syntax error while delete in joining

Tags: mysql

I am using to delete some records,

```
delete FROM product_to_category c inner JOIN product_description d 
ON c.product_id = d.product_id
WHERE c.category_id IN (3, 6)
GROUP BY c.product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id) = 2
ORDER BY d.name asc
```

but it return syntax error to use near `c inner JOIN product_description............`

can anyone tell me how i construct my query correct

any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Try `delete product_to_category  FROM product_to_category INNER JOIN product_description d`

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one table (joins) you need to specify which table to delete..

```
DELETE T1
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.key = T2.key
WHERE condition
```